# How to get random numbers with percent to show

Tags: vb.net, random, numbers

**Hi i'm creating a program in vb that can generate random numbers. the thing is i want to lessen the chance to appear the highest number.**

for Example i have numbers from 1-10 (in ramdom)

Number 10 the chance to appear is 10%

Number 9 the chance to appear is 20%

Number 8 the chance to appear is 30%
etc..

**here is my sample code.**

```
        Dim R1 As New Random
        Dim d1result1 As Integer = R1.Next(1, 10)
        Label2.Text = d1result1.ToString
```

Comment: You should start by understanding how the `Random` class works. If you call `Next(1, 10)` then you are asking for a number in the range 1 - 9.  The `minValue` parameter is inclusive but the `maxValue` parameter is exclusive, as stated clearly in the documentation and thus by Intellisense.  If you want a maximum value of 10 to be generated then you must pass 11 to the `maxValue` parameter.

Comment: Fun fact: Per cent means *amount per hundred*.  If you add your 3 example values together, the sum is already 60% and the next value would be 40% thus exhausting the weightings.  And if you did `etc..` down to 1, the weight would be 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extension method that can help you do as you want here:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module RandomExtensions

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a random integer that is within a specified range where each value in that range has a weighted probablity.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="source">
    ''' The <see cref="Random"/> object to use to generate the number.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="minValue">
    ''' The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="maxValue">
    ''' The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="weightings">
    ''' The weightings for each of the possible outcomes.
    ''' </param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' A non-negative weighting must be provided for each possible outcome.  Weightings are a proportion of the total of all weightings.  They are not percentages.
    ''' For instance, if there are three possible outcomes and the weightings are 1, 2 and 3 then the first outcome will result in about 1/6 of the time, the second outcome will result about 1/3 of the time and the third outcome will result about 1/2 of the time.
    ''' </remarks>
    <Extension>
    Public Function NextWithWeighting(source As Random,
                                      minValue As Integer,
                                      maxValue As Integer,
                                      ParamArray weightings As Integer()) As Integer
        If minValue > maxValue Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("'minValue' cannot be greater than maxValue.", "minValue")
        End If

        If maxValue > minValue AndAlso weightings.Length <> maxValue - minValue Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("A weighting must be provided for all possible outcomes.", "weightings")
        End If

        If weightings.Any(Function(n) n < 0) Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("All weightings must be greater than zero.", "weightings")
        End If

        Dim totalWeightings As Integer

        Try
            totalWeightings = weightings.Sum()
        Catch ex As OverflowException
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The sum of all weightings must not be greater than Int32.MaxValue.", ex)
        End Try

        If totalWeightings = 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("The sum of all weightings must be greater than zero.", "weightings")
        End If

        If minValue = maxValue OrElse minValue = maxValue + 1 Then
            'There is only one possible value.
            Return minValue
        End If

        'Generate a number in the range 0 to 1 less than the total weightings.
        Dim number = source.Next(totalWeightings)

        Dim runningWeighting As Integer

        'For each weighting, check whether the number generated falls in that interval.
        For i = 0 To weightings.GetUpperBound(0)
            'Sum the weightings so far.
            'E.g. if the weightings are 10, 20, 30 and 40 then the running weighting for each iteration will be:
            'i = 0: runningWeighting = 0 + 10 = 10
            'i = 1: runningWeighting = 10 + 20 = 30
            'i = 2: runningWeighting = 30 + 30 = 60
            'i = 3: runningWeighting = 60 + 40 = 100
            runningWeighting += weightings(i)

            'There is no interval until the running weighting is greater than zero.
            If runningWeighting > 0 AndAlso number <= runningWeighting Then
                'The number generated falls within the current weighting interval so get the value from the original range that corresponds to that interval.
                Return minValue + i
            End If
        Next

        'If we end up here then something was wrong with the interval and/or the weightings.
        'The validation at the top of the method should ensure that such cases are always caught first.
        Throw New Exception("An unexpected error occurred.")
    End Function

End Module
```

Declaring it as an extension method means that you can call it on your `Random` instance, just as you would call `Next`, e.g.

```
Dim rng As New Random

'Get an unweighted random number in the range 1 - 3.
Dim n1 = rng.Next(1, 4)

'Use weightings of 20%, 30% and 50% for values 1, 2 and 3 respectively.
Dim weightings = {2, 3, 5}

'Get a weighted random number in the range 1 - 3.
Dim n1 = rng.NextWithWeighting(1, 4, weightings)
```

Note that, because the `weightings` parameter is declared as a `ParamArray`, those last two lines could be replaced with this:

```
Dim n1 = rng.NextWithWeighting(1, 4, 2, 3, 5)
```

If you don't want to call this as an extension method then you can call it like this instead:

```
Dim n1 = NextWithWeighting(rng, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5)
```

If you don't add the `Extension` attribute then you have to call it the second way.

Here's a test rig that demonstrates how to use this method and that it does as expected:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim rng As New Random
        Dim countsByNumber As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) From {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}}

        'Generate 1000 random numbers in the range 1 - 4 inclusive and count the number of times each result is generated.
        'Use the following weighting: 1 - 10%, 2 - 20%, 3 - 30%, 4 - 40%
        For i = 1 To 1000
            Dim number = rng.NextWithWeighting(1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40)

            'The above line could also be written like this:
            'Dim weightings = {10, 20, 30, 40}
            'Dim number = rng.NextWithWeighting(1, 5, weightings)

            'Increment the count for the generated number.
            countsByNumber(number) += 1
        Next

        'Output the counts to see if they are close to the weightings.
        For Each number In countsByNumber.Keys
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", number, countsByNumber(number))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

If you put that code into a Console app and run it repeatedly, you'll see that 1 gets generated about 100 times, 2 gets generated about 200 times, 3 gets generated about 300 times and 4 gets generated about 400 times, all in line with the specified weightings.

In your specific case, you haven't specified what the full weightings are so I can't give you the exact code but it would be something like this:

```
Dim R1 As New Random
Dim weightings = {w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, 30, 20, 10}
Dim d1result1 As Integer = R1.NextWithWeighting(1, 11, weightings)

Label2.Text = d1result1.ToString()
```

where `w1`, `w2`, ..., `w7` are `Integer` values that sum to 40.

EDIT: If you want to see how the code handles zero weightings, try changing this line:

```
Dim number = rng.NextWithWeighting(1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40)
```

to this:

```
Dim number = rng.NextWithWeighting(1, 5, 10, 20, 0, 40)
```

or this:

```
Dim number = rng.NextWithWeighting(1, 5, 0, 0, 30, 0)
```

Comment: Please use my delaclared variable. i dont get it.

Comment: Note that the above also handles individual zero weightings, as long as at least one weighting is greater than zero.

Comment: Am I calling this correctly? I am not getting the results I expected. 
   Dim weightings = {18, 16, 14, 13, 11, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2}                       
    Dim d1result1 As Integer = R1.NextWithWeighting(1, 11, weightings)

Comment: Firstly, if you want to format code in a comment then wrap it in ` characters (on the same key as ~). As for the question, what did you expect and exactly how did the result not correlate to your expectations?  Did you modify my test rig appropriately to test those weightings?

Comment: `Dim weightings = {18, 16, 14, 13, 11, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2}`
               `Dim d1result1 As Integer = R1.NextWithWeighting(1, 11, weightings)`  I expected percentages as in the weightings but got way different percentages.

Comment: Like what? I just tested and it looks pretty good to me. Not exactly what I'd expect, so I might have a closer look. Pretty close though, so it could just be margin of error.

Comment: It just occurred to me that maybe you're saying that you would expect to generate 100 numbers and get exactly that many of each possible outcome. That wouldn't be what you asked for. This code treats every random number generation in isolation. Just as if you generated 100 numbers without weightings, you'd expect to get about 10 of each but not necessarily exactly that and the actual proportions would change each run, so in this case you'd expect about those proportions but not exactly.

Answer (score 0):

First, I made a little structure to hold the digits and the weight percent.

```
Structure Weights

        Public Sub New(num As Integer, per As Integer)
            Number = num
            Percent = per
        End Sub
        Public Number As Integer
        Public Percent As Integer
End Structure
```

Then I filled a list of the structure. Next I looped through the lstWeights and added digits to a second list; adding each digit to the lst x number of times based on the percent weight.

```
Private Sub BuildWeightedList()
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(10, 2))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(9, 4))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(8, 5))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(7, 8))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(6, 9))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(5, 11))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(4, 13))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(3, 14))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(2, 16))
        lstWeights.Add(New Weights(1, 18))
        'Add digits to lst; each digit is added as many times as it weight
        For Each item As Weights In lstWeights
            For x As Integer = 1 To item.Percent
                lst.Add(item.Number)
            Next
        Next
End Sub
```

Now to get the random weighted digits (1-10) Remember there are 18 ones, a16 twos, 14 threes etc. Generate a random index and get the digit at that index. For testing purposes, I added the result to yet another list.

```
Private Sub WeightedRandom()
        Dim ListCount As Integer = lst.Count
        Dim index As Integer = R1.Next(0, ListCount)
        Dim d1result1 As Integer = lst(index)
        lstResult.Add(d1result1)
End Sub
```

Classes level variables:

```
Private lstWeights As New List(Of Weights)
Private lst As New List(Of Integer)
Private lstResult As New List(Of Integer)
Private R1 As New Random
```

In the form load build the first list. lstWeights

```
BuildWeightedList()
```

Call the procedure from a button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For x = 0 To 10000
            WeightedRandom()
        Next
        TestWeighted()
         MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub
```

Then I tested thusly:

```
Private Sub TestWeighted()
        Dim c10, c9, c8, c7, c6, c5, c4, c3, c2, c1 As Integer
        For Each x As Integer In lstResult
            Select Case x
                Case 1
                    c1 += 1
                Case 2
                    c2 += 1
                Case 3
                    c3 += 1
                Case 4
                    c4 += 1
                Case 5
                    c5 += 1
                Case 6
                    c6 += 1
                Case 7
                    c7 += 1
                Case 8
                    c8 += 1
                Case 9
                    c9 += 1
                Case 10
                    c10 += 1
            End Select
        Next
        Dim divisor As Integer = lstResult.Count
        Debug.Print($"1 is {c1 / divisor:P00}, 2 is {c2 / divisor:P00}, 3 is {c3 / divisor:P00}, 4 is {c4 / divisor:P00}, 5 is {c5 / divisor:P00}, 6 is {c6 / divisor:P00}, 7 is {c7 / divisor:P00}, 8 is {c8 / divisor:P00}, 9 is {c9 / divisor:P00}, 10 is {c10 / divisor:P00},")
End Sub
```

The result in the immediate window:

```
1 is 18%, 2 is 17%, 3 is 13%, 4 is 13%, 5 is 11%, 6 is 9%, 7 is 8%, 8 is 5%, 9 is 4%, 10 is 2%,
```

then to test John's extension

```
Private Sub Testjmcilhinney()
        Dim R1 As New Random 'CORRECTION - moved this to class level
        'Dim weightings = {100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10}
        'Took the weights provided by the OP and divided by 550 (total of his percentages) to get weightings totaling 100
        Dim weightings = {18, 16, 14, 13, 11, 9, 8, 5, 4, 2} 'Totals 100%
        Dim d1result1 As Integer = R1.NextWithWeighting(1, 11, weightings)
        lstResult.Add(d1result1)
End Sub

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For x = 0 To 10000
         Testjmcilhinney()
        Next
        TestWeighted()
        MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub
```

result in immediate window

```
1 is 60%, 2 is 0%, 3 is 21%, 4 is 0%, 5 is 0%, 6 is 19%, 7 is 0%, 8 is 0%, 9 is 0%, 10 is 0%,
```

second try

```
1 is 0%, 2 is 0%, 3 is 0%, 4 is 53%, 5 is 0%, 6 is 3%, 7 is 0%, 8 is 44%, 9 is 0%, 10 is 0%,
```

I am obviously doing something very wrong.
After correction (see comment)

```
1 is 19%, 2 is 17%, 3 is 14%, 4 is 13%, 5 is 11%, 6 is 9%, 7 is 9%, 8 is 4%, 9 is 4%, 10 is 1%,
```

Comment: Got it! Moved Dim R1 As New Random to class level and results then made sense. This is in a tight loop and I was getting duplicate values with jmcilhinney code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number